# Dynamically Social-Engine form element addition onchange of a specific form element

Tags: php, socialengine

I am new in SE 4.20. I am having a problem of creating a form element onchange of this form element.

For explanation,
 I have a form. I am able to return some select option value on change of this form element. But now I want to add a form element on change of this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a form element, like a text box, if the user changes the select box? Maybe something like:

```
$("#selectBoxId").change(function (){
    $("#formId").append("<input type='text' name='additionalFormElement' />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the html:

```
<div class="form-elements">
<div id="typeName-wrapper" class="form-wrapper">
    <div id="typeName-label" class="form-label">
        <label for="typeName" class="required">Type</label>
    </div>
    <div id="typeName-element" class="form-element">
        <select name="typeName" id="typeName">
            <option value="Grant">Grant</option>
            <option value="Cooperative Agreements">Cooperative Agreements</option>
            <option value="Publication">Publication</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="resourceName-wrapper" class="form-wrapper">
    <div id="resourceName-label" class="form-label">
        <label for="resourceName" class="required">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div id="resourceName-element" class="form-element">
        <select name="resourceName" id="resourceName">
            <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
            <option value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the mootool js:

```
 $('typeName').addEvent('change', function(event) {
        var typeName = $('typeName').value;
        var base_path = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>/";
        var url = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/test/resource/getresourcebytype';
        var request= new Request.JSON({
            url: url,
            method: 'GET',
            data: {"typeName":typeName},
            onSuccess: function( response )
            {
                console.log(response);
                //clear the select box
                var name = $('resourceName');
                while (name.firstChild) {
                    name.removeChild(name.firstChild);
                }
                //now add new option
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                    console.log(response[i]);
                    new Element('option', {'value': response[i].value, 'text':response[i].label}).inject(name);
                }

            }, onFailure: function(){

                console.log('failed');
            }
        });
        request.send();
    });
```